# Minecraft Forge Modding 1.18.1 Ore Generation Confusion

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

This problem doesn't have a solution to me but I hope you will. I have only experienced forge modding in 1.16.5 and in 1.18.1, there is so much Confusion, My Brain is Literally Broken and I have Dizziness just looking at it. I followed a code from 1.17 from TurtyWurty and this is it:

```
public static final List<ConfiguredFeature<?, ?>> OVERWORLD_ORES = new ArrayList<>();
public static final List<ConfiguredFeature<?, ?>> END_ORES = new ArrayList<>();
public static final List<ConfiguredFeature<?, ?>> NETHER_ORES = new ArrayList<>();

public static final RuleTest END_TEST = new BlockMatchTest(Blocks.END_STONE);

public static void registerOres() {
    ConfiguredFeature<?, ?> bronzeOre = Feature.ORE
            .configured(new OreConfiguration(List.of(
                    OreConfiguration.target(OreFeatures.STONE_ORE_REPLACEABLES,
                            Blocks.GLOWSTONE.defaultBlockState())),
                    11));
    bronzeOre.placed(commonOrePlacement(8, HeightRangePlacement.triangle(VerticalAnchor.bottom(), VerticalAnchor.aboveBottom(20))));
    OVERWORLD_ORES.add(register("bronze_ore", bronzeOre));

}

private static <Config extends FeatureConfiguration> ConfiguredFeature<Config, ?> register(String name,
                                                                                           ConfiguredFeature<Config, ?> configuredFeature) {
    return Registry.register(BuiltinRegistries.CONFIGURED_FEATURE, new ResourceLocation(FendersMetalMod.MOD_ID, name),
            configuredFeature);
}

@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = FendersMetalMod.MOD_ID, bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.FORGE)
public static class ForgeBusSubscriber {
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void biomeLoading(BiomeLoadingEvent event) {
        List<Supplier<ConfiguredFeature<?, ?>>> features = event.getGeneration()
                .getFeatures(GenerationStep.Decoration.UNDERGROUND_ORES);

        switch(event.getCategory()) {
            default -> MetalOreGen.OVERWORLD_ORES.forEach(ore -> features.add(() -> ore));
        }
    }
}

private static List<PlacementModifier> orePlacement(PlacementModifier p_195347_, PlacementModifier p_195348_) {
    return List.of(p_195347_, InSquarePlacement.spread(), p_195348_, BiomeFilter.biome());
}

private static List<PlacementModifier> commonOrePlacement(int p_195344_, PlacementModifier p_195345_) {
    return orePlacement(CountPlacement.of(p_195344_), p_195345_);
}
```

But the code has a problem, see in this part of the code:

```java
List<Supplier<ConfiguredFeature<?, ?>>> features = event.getGeneration()
                .getFeatures(GenerationStep.Decoration.UNDERGROUND_ORES);
```

It has an error in which I don't know but I think that:

"`event.getGeneration().getFeatures(GenerationStep.Decoration.UNDERGROUND_ORES);`"
is not correct and should provide a "`List<Supplier<ConfiguredFeature<?, ?>>>`"
because "`event.getGeneration().getFeatures(GenerationStep.Decoration.UNDERGROUND_ORES);`"
is a "`List<Supplier<PlacedFeature>>`", not a "`List<Supplier<ConfiguredFeature<?, ?>>>`".

I tried to change it but there are more errors that would appear if I would Change it.

Comment: Can you show the error ?

Comment: This isn't technically a Minecraft error, this is what IntelliJ is telling me:

Comment: Oh, it's when you develop not after compilation ? Just, what is "Placedfeature" ? (the import & if it's one of your class)

Comment: It's when developing and I don't know what in the world "PlacedFeature" is