# MinecraftForge 1.19.3 Ore Generation (Java Edition)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Tutorials for modding Minecraft using Minecraftforge use a constant called `BuiltInRegistries.CONFIGURED_FEATURE` to allow a mod to register a custom feature. This constant is missing from Minecraft 1.19.3.
For example, this solution to a similar problem doesn't work in 1.19:  [Minecraft Forge Modding 1.18.1 Ore Generation Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858824/minecraft-forge-modding-1-18-1-ore-generation-confusion)

Does anyone know what this has been replaced with in 1.19.3 or know of an updated tutorial. Here's what we're doing:

```
final Block MY_ORE_BLOCK = Registry.register(BuiltInRegistries.BLOCK, "my_ore", new DropExperienceBlock(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of(Material.STONE).requiresCorrectToolForDrops().strength(3.0F, 3.0F), UniformInt.of(3, 7)));
final ResourceKey<ConfiguredFeature<?, ?>> MY_ORE_LARGE = FeatureUtils.createKey("my_ore_large");
List<OreConfiguration.TargetBlockState> list = List.of(OreConfiguration.target(ruletest1, MY_ORE_BLOCK.defaultBlockState()));
ConfiguredFeature<?,?> feature = new ConfiguredFeature(Feature.ORE, new OreConfiguration(list, 4, 0.5F));
Registry.register(BuiltInRegistries.CONFIGURED_FEATURE, MY_ORE_LARGE, feature);
```

The purpose of the code being to create a new type of Ore and to register it as a feature so that the world generator generates deposits of it.

We tried to compile, but BuiltInRegistries doesn't have a `CONFIGURED_FEATURE` constant in 1.19.3 so that doesn't compile.
We also tried to use `FeatureUtils.register()` to register the feature but couldn't find how to get a BootstapContext to pass to its first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem. The authors of minecraftforge said that `ConfiguredFeature`s are now data driven. After a lot more research, I found that the following json files were needed in order to generate ore (no code needed except to create the new `Block`):

`data/mymod/worldgen/placed_feature/ore_mine.json`

```
    {
      "feature": "examplemod:ore_mine_small",
      "placement": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:count",
          "count": 16
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:in_square"
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:height_range",
          "height": {
            "type": "minecraft:trapezoid",
            "max_inclusive": {
              "absolute": 112
            },
            "min_inclusive": {
              "absolute": -16
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:biome"
        }
      ]
    }
```

`data/mymod/worldgen/configured_feature/ore_mine_small.json`

```
    {
      "type": "minecraft:ore",
      "config": {
        "discard_chance_on_air_exposure": 0.0,
        "size": 10,
        "targets": [
          {
            "state": {
              "Name": "examplemod:my_ore"
            },
            "target": {
              "predicate_type": "minecraft:tag_match",
              "tag": "minecraft:stone_ore_replaceables"
            }
          },
          {
            "state": {
              "Name": "examplemod:my_ore"
            },
            "target": {
              "predicate_type": "minecraft:tag_match",
              "tag": "minecraft:deepslate_ore_replaceables"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

`data/mymod/forge/biome_modifier/add_my_ore.json`

```
    {
      "type": "forge:add_features",
      "biomes": "#minecraft:is_overworld",
      "features": "examplemod:ore_mine_small",
      "step": "underground_ores"
    }
```

The first two files define how to place the new ore similarly to how built in ores are placed. The third file is what adds this configured feature to specific biomes. It was documented in `net.minecraftforge.common.world.ForgeBiomeModifiers`, but the documentation didn't clarify where the json file should be placed: `data/examplemod/forge/biome_modifier/`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`FEATURES`](https://nekoyue.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs-NG/javadoc/1.19.3/net/minecraftforge/registries/ForgeRegistries.html#FEATURES) [deferred registry](https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/1.19.2/concepts/registries/)

[Forge Docs on registries](https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/1.19.2/concepts/registries/), [Forge JavaDocs of `FEATURES` registry](https://nekoyue.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs-NG/javadoc/1.19.3/net/minecraftforge/registries/ForgeRegistries.html#FEATURES).

```java
private static final DeferredRegister<Feature<?>> FEATURES = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.FEATURES, MODID);
```